# In jQuery, why do I get unrecognized expression error when select option value is less than 1?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically populate select options using values (getval = 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25). Why am I getting unrecognized expression error when the value is less than 1:

```
html:
<option name={{ $papersizeItem['value'] }} >{{ $papersizeItem['title'] }}</option>

jquery:
var getval = 0.5;
$("#s2q14_1 option[name="+getval+"]").prop('selected', true);

Expected output:
<option name=0.5 selected>some name</option>

Error:
Unrecognized expression: #s2q14_1 option[name=0.5]
```

Comment: The window to the code is too narrow. Please paste a detailed code, context and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `.` in the `getval` value is being interpreted as a class selector. You cannot have a class selector within an attribute selector, so the sizzle engine returns that error.

To fix this wrap the attribute value in quotes so there is no ambiguity:

```
$('#s2q14_1 option[name="' + getval + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Alternative using a template literal:

```
$(`#s2q14_1 option[name="${getval}"]`).prop('selected', true);
```

It's also worth noting that `name` is not a valid attribute for the `option` element. I'd suggest finding an alternative, such as a `data` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
let getVal = 2.5;
 $(`#s2q14_1 option[name="${getVal}"]`).prop('selected', true);
```